# Angular 2 Highcharts Cannot read property 'info' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

i am trying to load some stock historical data into highchart but i am getting Cannot read property 'info' of undefined while using Angular 2 Highcharts. It works with one set of data but when i try different data it throws this error. wonder if it is something to do with saved instance and need a way to destroy the old chart in Angular 2. It seems like the same issue here, but not sure how to fix this in Angular2 highcharts [Cannot read property 'info' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795970/cannot-read-property-info-of-undefined)

```
<chart [options]="options" type="StockChart"
   (load)="saveInstance($event.context)">
```

Comment: Your code does not allow to reproduce the problem. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to recreate a live example of the issue on plunkr/jsfiddle/etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with the actual data and not highcharts. one of the json property in the data was Date which was in string format and wasn't getting converted to milliseconds.